# Tkinter - How to update Interface when upon selecting different choice in dropdown list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating a section anlysis GUI in python using `tkinter`.

I've created a drop down list and the interface can changes with different choice, but upon selecting for the second time, it seems the new interface(some entry or text) just covers the first interface.

I want to know how to delete the first interface so that interface can immediately update with the selection in dropdownlist.

Here is the code：

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk
def secdata( *args ):
    t = sectype.get()
    if t=='Rec_Shape':
        tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="REC_Width").grid(column=0, row=1)
        wid=tk.StringVar()
        widdata=tk.ttk.Entry(monty1,width=5,textvariable=wid)
        widdata.grid(column=1,row=1)
        tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="REC_Height").grid(column=0, row=2)
        hei=tk.StringVar()
        heidata=tk.ttk.Entry(monty1,width=5,textvariable=hei)
        heidata.grid(column=1,row=2)
    else:
        tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="Flange_Width").grid(column=0, row=1)
        wid1=tk.StringVar()
        wid1data=tk.ttk.Entry(monty1,width=5,textvariable=wid1)
        wid1data.grid(column=1,row=1)
        tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="Web_Width").grid(column=0, row=2)
        wid2=tk.StringVar()
        wid2data=tk.ttk.Entry(monty1,width=5,textvariable=wid2)
        wid2data.grid(column=1,row=2)
        tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="Flange_Height").grid(column=0, row=3)
        hei1=tk.StringVar()
        hei1data=tk.ttk.Entry(monty1,width=5,textvariable=hei1)
        hei1data.grid(column=1,row=3)
        tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="Total_Height").grid(column=0, row=4)
        hei2=tk.StringVar()
        hei2data=tk.ttk.Entry(monty1,width=5,textvariable=hei2)
        hei2data.grid(column=1,row=4)
window=tk.Tk()
window.title('Section Analysis')
window.geometry('500x400')
tabControl=tk.ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1=tk.ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1,text='Bending')
tabControl.pack(expand=1,fill='both')

monty1=tk.ttk.LabelFrame(tab1,text='Bending')
monty1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)
tk.ttk.Label(monty1, text="Sectype:").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
sectype=tk.ttk.Combobox(monty1,state='readonly')
sectype.grid(column=1, row=0)
sectype['value']=('Rec_Shape','T_Shape')
sectype.current(0)
sectype.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",secdata)
monty1.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Rethink your approach, if you want to **recreate** the widgets, you have to `.destroy()` it before. Read [An Introduction To Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your help , and the problme has been solved by the advice you give.